# QGIS Points to path using

Tags: point, linear-referencing

I've one question or maybe two about Points to path in QGIS. 
First, I present my case:
I have to do "travel paths" from one address to another address. 
I have a database - example:
[image]
How I should arrange the data and prepare them to use the Points to path? Should I use some other tool?

Comment: Your first question should be how to get the geographic coordinates for your addresses, or have you done this already?

Comment: If you find you want to ask two questions then please ask the second one in a separate question (see [Tour]).

Comment: First you need to geocode your addresses to get points on a map. Then you need to route between the two. I have 3 years of working with QGIS, I can do this but it would take me at least 3 days to complete. This might be trickier than you envisage.

Comment: @Vesanto - I've geographic coordinates for addresses. I mean how it looks: in Points to path are two fields: group and order. How I should arrange a database to make it work? I did something like this before and sometimes it did not work properly.